# Problem with Matic tokens(Polygon)

Tags: metamask, polygon

I hope you are all well.
There is something I don't udnerstand. I have matic tokens(polygon tokens) in my metamask under the main ethereum network(mainnet).
I had configured the matic mainnet in my metamask so why did the matic tokens arrive in the main ethereum network?

Therefore do you know how I could send my matic tokens under the matic mainnet in my metamask?

I can see the my matik tokens on etherscan but not on Polygonscan. Do you know why?

Thank you very much

Take care

Pierre

Answer (score 0):

Because you sent them on ethereum mainnet. You can bridge them to the polygon network using https://wallet.matic.network/bridge/

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to hear that your Matic tokens are giving you trouble. Make sure you're using the right wallet and that you're following the steps that Polygon gives you. If you're still having trouble, I'll tell you what worked for me.